# How do I prove the following inequality involving exponential functions

Tags: calculus, analysis, inequality

Let $R>2$ be a real number. Then, for any $n\geq 1$, it holds that

$$ \frac{ \exp(n R)+ 1}{\exp( n R) - \exp(\pi R/2)}  \leq \exp(  R/n^2).$$

How do I prove this?

Comment: For $n=1$ the inequality:
$$e^R+1\leq e^R(e^R-e^{\pi R/2})$$
is false, because $e^{(1+\pi/2)R}\geq e^{2R}-e^R-1$ for $R\geq 0$.

Answer (score 3):

The inequality as stated:
$$
   \frac{ \exp(n R)+ 1}{\exp( n R) - \exp(\pi R/2)}  \leq \exp(  R/n^2)
$$
can not be true for all $R>2$ and $n \geq 1$. Indeed, choose $n=2$, then for all $2 < r < r_\ast$, the inequality does not hold, where $r_\ast$ is the unique positive root of 
$$
   e^{2 r}-e^{9 r/4}+\exp\left({\frac{\pi  r}{2}+\frac{r}{4}}\right)+1 
$$
approximately equal $r_\ast \approx 2.118953$.

[image]